# How to label an equation with number?

Tags: equations, numbering

I am using LaTeX version 3.77. I am trying to label my equations but every method appeared online won't seem to work for me for some reason.

```
\begin{document}
Below is the equation I am typing, and I would like it to be numbered [1]
\[A_t = P_t^K + B_t + M_t\]

Below is the equation I would like to be numbered [2]
\[a_t = p_t^K + b_t + m_t\] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `equation` instead of `\[ \]`?

Comment: Exactly which online methods have you looked at. Any normal introduction to LaTeX would include how you number equations. If the one you found did not, please tell ud which so we can tell people not to use them.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Below is the equation I am typing, and I would like it to be numbered [1]
\begin{equation}
  A_t = P_t^K + B_t + M_t
\end{equation}

Below is the equation I would like to be numbered [2]
\begin{equation}
  a_t = p_t^K + b_t + m_t
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]